# Why am I not able to scale or set position of a mesh in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

As you can see below, I added a mesh to the scene but everytime I try to scale it or set position, I get an error that the mesh is null.

```
  mesh2.position.set(0,0,-5);
  mesh2.scale.set(0.2, 0.3, 0.2);
```

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of null*

check it out at [testing2.site44.com](http://testing2.site44.com)

Please help as I have wasted hours trying to get this to work.

```
function init()
{
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();//CREATE NEW THREE JS SCENE

    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true}); //INIT NEW THREE JS RENDERER
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio ); //SET PIXEL RATIO FOR MOBILE DEVICES
        renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color('#005b96'), 1) //SET BG COLOR
        renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT); // SET SIZE
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); //APPLY CANVAS TO BODY
        renderer.domElement.id = "canvas_threeJS";//ADD ID TO CANVAS

    //ADD CAMERA TO THE SCENE
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR =1000;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
        camera.position.set(0,3,8); //SET CAMERA POSITION
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-5));
        scene.add(camera);

    //ADD AMBIENT LIGHT
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight("#6497b1");
        scene.add(ambientLight);

    //HANDLE WINDOW RESIZE
    //ADD MAIN LIGHT
    var light = new THREE.PointLight("#b3cde0",.6);
        light.position.set(-5,13,-1);
        scene.add(light);


    var mesh2 = null;
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('assets/models/spaceship001.json', function(geometry) {
        mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
        scene.add(mesh2);
        console.log("done loading model");
        });


      mesh2.position.set(0,0,-5);
//    mesh2.scale.set(0.2, 0.3, 0.2);


    //START POSITION OF A LEVEL GROUP
    var levelSpawn = -100;

    //GET VISIBLE WIDTH AT levelSpawn POSITION
    var vFOV = camera.fov * Math.PI / 180; // convert vertical fov to radians
    var height = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 )*levelSpawn; // visible height

    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var width = height * aspect;// visible width

    //START RENDER
    update();

    function update()
    {

        //UPDATE 3D SCENE
        renderer.render( scene, camera );

        //KEEP RENDERING
        requestAnimationFrame( update );
    }


}
```

Comment: Loading Models is asynchron. Your code is executed before the model is loaded, place it inside your callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that javascript is an asynchronous language. Depending on your background you should read up on that. Try putting a `console.log("setting scale and postion")` just under or above those two lines. What you'll notice is that the position and scale is set **before** the mesh is loaded.

What you need to do is set the position and scale inside the callback function that you pass to the load function, just under the `console.log("done loading model");` line.

You can also read up on javascript Promises to understand it better.